# C# DTLS Certificate Verify Message

Tags: c#, x509certificate, private-key, dtls

I need to start using `SNMPv3` over `DTLS` with certificates from the windows certificate store in c# and from what I've seen so far, this isn't used very often at all. Unfortunately, I have no choice in the matter.

I'm working on using `DTLS.NET` to do the handshake. One trick is that `DTLS.NET`seems to want a `pem` file instead of an `X509 Certificate` from the Windows Certificate Store. I believe I've figured out how to load the cert, except the private key. The private key is not exportable, and I don't believe I can change that.

```
public void LoadX509Certificate(X509Certificate2 certificate)
{
    if (certificate == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(certificate));
    }

    this._PrivateKey = DotNetUtilities.GetKeyPair(certificate.PrivateKey).Private;

    this._Certificate = new Certificate
    {
        CertChain = new List<byte[]>() { certificate.RawData },
        CertificateType = TCertificateType.X509
    };
}
```

I believe I've figured out up to the certificate verify message and that's where it appears to need the private key.

```
CertificateVerify certificateVerify = new CertificateVerify();
byte[] signatureHash = _HandshakeInfo.GetHash();
certificateVerify.SignatureHashAlgorithm = new SignatureHashAlgorithm() { Signature = TSignatureAlgorithm.ECDSA, Hash = THashAlgorithm.SHA256 };
certificateVerify.Signature = TLSUtils.Sign(_PrivateKey, true, _Version, _HandshakeInfo, certificateVerify.SignatureHashAlgorithm, signatureHash);
SendHandshakeMessage(certificateVerify, false);
```

I can't seem to find much information in the RFCs or elsewhere that describe exactly what needs to happen here. I do know that the server can handle `RSA`, `DSS`, or `ECDSA`, so I left it with `ECDSA` since that's what `DTLS.NET` is using.

Do I actually need the private key to create the `CertificateVerify` message?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The handshake may authenticate the client by it's certificate. 
Though the certificate on it's own is "public", everyone would be able to send it and the authentication could not be granted.
Therefore the client has to proof, that he has access to the private key as well. That's why the "Certificate Verify" message is used.

If you don't have access to the private key of your public key of your certificate, a client certificate handshake is not possible.

Maybe the keystore doesn't export that private key, but offer instead a "signing" function, where that privte key is applied.

Comment: You are correct! I ended up loading the private key as an RSA

(RSACryptoServiceProvider)mainCert.PrivateKey;

and then 

rsa.SignData(hash, HashAlgorithmName.SHA1, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

thanks!